# how to set margin function for divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two rings orbit around a central point. The margins look to be correct, but then the divs show up in a bunch of random places. How should I fix this?
Also where is the point that the divs starts at before it does the margin

```css
.shell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: spin-right 1s linear infinite;
}
.electrons {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
#electron1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
#electron2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
#electron3 {
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: -90px;
}
#electron4 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
#electron5 {
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
#electron6 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: -90px;
}
#electron7 {
  margin-top: -90px;
}
#electron8 {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
#electron9 {
  margin-left: -90px;
}
#electron10 {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
@keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="electrons" id="electron1"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron2"></div>
</div>
<div class="shell">
  <div class="electrons" id="electron3"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron4"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron5"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron6"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron7"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron8"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron9"></div>
  <div class="electrons" id="electron10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is css.shell{
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       height: 1px;
       width: 1px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       background-color: black; 
       animation: spin-right 1s linear infinite;
      }
      .electrons{
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       text-align: center;
       visibility: visible;
       border-radius: 50%;
       background-color: green;
       height: 25px;
       width: 25px;
      }
      #electron1{
       visibility: hidden;
       margin-top: -60px;
       margin-left: -60px;
      }

Comment: #electron2{
       visibility: hidden;
       margin-top: 60px;
       margin-left: 60px;
      }
      #electron3{
       margin-top: -90px;
       margin-left: -90px;
      }
      #electron4{
       margin-top: 90px;
       margin-left: 90px;
      }
      #electron5{
       margin-top: -90px;
       margin-left: 90px;
      }
      #electron6{
       margin-top: 90px;
       margin-left: -90px;
      }
      #electron7{
       margin-top: -90px;
      }

Comment: #electron8{
       margin-left: 90px;
      }
      #electron9{
       margin-left: -90px;
      }
      #electron10{
       margin-top: 90px;
      }
      @keyframes spin-right {
       100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
      }
      body{
       background-color: black;
      }

Comment: Use Codepen to post your example.

Answer (score 1):

If I undertood you well to avoid those random places you just need to add `position: absolute` to your `.electrons` class : )

Check it here without the animation: https://jsfiddle.net/mshjy8re/

Same example with custom tags:

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a-shell {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: spin-right 1s linear infinite;
}

a-electron {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

a-electron:first-child {
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: -90px;
}

a-electron:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

a-electron:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

a-electron:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: -90px;
}

a-electron:nth-child(5) {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

a-electron:nth-child(6) {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

a-electron:nth-child(7) {
  margin-left: -90px;
}

a-electron:last-child {
  margin-top: 90px;
}

@keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<a-shell>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
  <a-electron></a-electron>
</a-shell>
```

Hope this help ^^